# submitting form data on jquery button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button by where onclick i am trying to send the form data to the server page to process. but somehow the formdata is going empty

can anyone guide what i am doing wrong here, here is my code

```
function ajax(obj) {
    alert('hello');
    console.log(obj);
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    var data = new FormData(form);
    var post_url = $('#formid').attr("action"); //get form action url
    var form_data = $('#formid').serialize() & '&yes=1'; //Encode form elements for submission 
    console.log(form_data);
    console.log(data);
    $.post(post_url, form_data, function( response ) {
        $("#results").html(response);
    });
    return false;
}
```

the function ajax is called on the button click inside a form

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's a little unclear why you create `data` yet then do not use it to Post `data`. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and you should take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: You may just need to prevent the page from submitting.  Call event.preventDefault() in your handler

Comment: Appears like you are mixing post form data and string append (the &yes=1 parameter).
skip the serialize and just use data.append('yes', '1');
then use data instead of $('#formid').serialize()

Comment: Juts t be clear code looks confusing:
the & operator is a logical operator !! 
the result will be boolean true - and this will be send to server.
for concatenating strings + is used

Answer (score 0):

You are using post menthod wich gets params in body serilliazing the args like that is good for GET request you should send in body just use a object holding all the info

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data ,// object
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: but it is showing my an error  Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation 

https://prnt.sc/NtsoirC3Z8Nm

Comment: can you provide live example?